# AskTimeoutException: Timed out - Play Framework 2.1

Tags: playframework, timeout, playframework-2.1

I'm developing a metaheuristic algorithm in Play framework and must have an indefinite timeout. After an hour of loaded I get the following error:

[AskTimeoutException: Timed out]

```
! @6g40d7af9 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/planificar] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AskTimeoutException: Timed out]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:144) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:140) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Promise.scala:104) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:310) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.DefaultScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:193) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:137) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1417) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?. 
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is my Controller

```
public static Result planificar() {
        Carga.cargarGlobales();
        Moacs moacs = new Moacs(cargarParametros());
        moacs.ejecutar(); // metaheuristics algorithm
        List<Solucion> soluciones =  moacs.getConjuntoPareto();            
        return ok(soluciones);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make this an async controller: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync

Comment: Thanks, async made ​​my algorithm is slower (I do not know why), but now works correctly.

Comment: That is odd.  It shouldn't be any slower.

Answer (score 0):

You could set Timeout to a very large value. From Scala [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration), the range of `FiniteDuration` is limited to +-(2^63-1)ns, which is roughly 292 years.

For example, one could do this:

```
(someActor ? someMsg)(365 Days).map { x => .... }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering but where and how I can change the time limit?

Comment: Given your recent edit, James Ward's response is what you need.